# How to correctly store the dialog state (show or not)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to work with dialogs correctly in compose? Not in terms of implementing the dialogs themselves, but in terms of storing the state of the dialogs (whether to display it or not)
Here, for example, are all the screen states:

`sealed class NewsFeedScreenState {

```
object Initial : NewsFeedScreenState() 

object Loading : NewsFeedScreenState() 

data class Posts( 
    val posts: List<FeedPost>, 
    val nextDataIsLoading: Boolean = false 
) : NewsFeedScreenState() 

data class Bookmarks( 
    val bookmarks: List<Bookmark>, 
    val nextDataIsLoading: Boolean = false 
) : NewsFeedScreenState()
```

}`

How would it be correct to implement AlertDialog state storage here (or not here)? The first thing that comes to mind is to add a boolean variable for each screen. Something similar to:

`  sealed class NewsFeedScreenState {

```
    object Initial : NewsFeedScreenState()

    data class Loading(
        val showDialog: Boolean,
    ) : NewsFeedScreenState()

    data class Posts(
        val showDialog: Boolean,
        val posts: List<FeedPost>,
        val nextDataIsLoading: Boolean = false
    ) : NewsFeedScreenState()

    data class Bookmarks(
        val showDialog: Boolean,
        val bookmarks: List<Bookmark>,
        val nextDataIsLoading: Boolean = false
    ) : NewsFeedScreenState()
}`
```

Is this the right decision? I would like to know the correct option, how this should really work. And if there can be 5 or ten different notifications/dialogs on this screen, then what would be the most correct way to implement this?

Comment: You need separate state variable for showing dialog and which must use ```SharedFlow``` in viewmodel.